# I have to fetch the data from multiple tables separately from BigQuery into same dataframe using python in local laptop

Tags: python, dataframe, google-bigquery, fetch

I have been able to fetch data from one table at a time. Only the **date changes in the table name** ,I have to pull data of 300 days . **Wanted to ask is it possible to pass table names in a list/array and run loop** and stores the data into one dataframe .

Code for One table at a time

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="C:/Users/GA/credentials.json"

client = bigquery.Client()
dflist = []

def query_data(QUERY,client,df):  
    query_job = client.query(QUERY) 
    query_result = query_job.result()
    df = query_result.to_dataframe()
    print(df.shape)
    dflist.append(df)
    return df,dflist
QUERY = (
    """
    SELECT 
    fullVisitorId,
    visitNumber,
    visitId,
    visitStartTime,
    date,
    totals.bounces,
    totals.hits,
    totals.newVisits,
    totals.pageviews,
    totals.screenviews,
    totals.sessionQualityDim,
    totals.timeOnScreen,
    totals.timeOnSite,
    totals.totalTransactionRevenue,
    totals.transactionRevenue,
    totals.transactions
FROM 
    bigquery-public-data:google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170715
    order by fullVisitorId, date, visitNumber, hitNumber
    """
    )

df = pd.DataFrame()
datafr,datals = query_data(QUERY,client,df)
finaldf = pd.concat(datals,axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use an f-string here to just insert so to say your table name into the query

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="C:/Users/GA/credentials.json"

client = bigquery.Client()
dflist = []

QUERY = (
    """
    SELECT 
    fullVisitorId,
    visitNumber,
    visitId,
    visitStartTime,
    date,
    totals.bounces,
    totals.hits,
    totals.newVisits,
    totals.pageviews,
    totals.screenviews,
    totals.sessionQualityDim,
    totals.timeOnScreen,
    totals.timeOnSite,
    totals.totalTransactionRevenue,
    totals.transactionRevenue,
    totals.transactions
FROM 
    bigquery-public-data:google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_{date}
    order by fullVisitorId, date, visitNumber, hitNumber
    """
    )

def query_data(date_:str) -> pd.DataFrame:  
    query_job = client.query(QUERY.format(date=date_)) 
    query_result = query_job.result()
    return query_result.to_dataframe()

dates = ["2021", "2022", ...]

finaldf = pd.concat((query_data(date) for date in dates),axis = 0)
```

note that you don't have to explicitly pass the client and the query to the function as it can just use them from the surrounding scope.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . The error was coming with * related to concat line of code TypeError: concat() got multiple values for argument 'axis'. Its working fine without * . Can you please explain the reason of using * in it .

Comment: Remove the *, was wrong on that.